# How to parse a text file and find a string between two other

Tags: c#, string, parsing

For example, let's say I have this:

```
string test = "id:test THISISTHESTRINGIWANT id2:test"
```

And I want to get THISISTHESTRINGIWANT. In order to do that I was wondering if its possible to find it like this:
left_string = "id:test ", right_string = " id2"

Thank You

Comment: ok I may have gave a wrong example....

Comment: `id:test\s(.+?)\sid2` This regex can capture it.

Comment: Is this a one-off requirement or is there a wider context? What are really trying to each, e.g. is it related to parsing input from some source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.split` like this

```
string test = "id:test THISISTHESTRINGIWANT id2:test"
char[] delimiterChars = { ' '};
string[] output= test.Split(delimiterChars);
```

this will give you 3 strings {id:test,THISISTHESTRINGIWANT,id2:test}
you can then iterate through the string array with whatever condition you want to weed out the unwanted data or you can change the `char` array to include any characters you want to split on.